# How to use collections in Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have such collection:

```
data[1]['Monday'] = 2
data[1]['Tuesday'] = 2
data[2]['Monday'] = 5
data[2]['Tuesday'] = 7
```

And would like to use it in django template.
When I did:

```
{{ data}}
```

Everything is displaying correct. But if I try e.g.:
{{ data.1 }}

Then I see empty collection.
Does anyone know why ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What type is `data` ? a `dict` ? a `list` ? Something else ? And when you say you "see empty collection", what do you get _exactly_ ? (generated html please).

Comment: Type is dict and I am getting "defaultdict(<function rec_dd at 0x7fc95115ec08>, {})"

Comment: Can you try with a `dict` you build manually in your view with : `data = {1 : {"Monday":2, "Tuesday:2}, 2: {"Monday": 5, "Tuesday": 7}}` ? And in your template display both `{{ data }}` and `{{ data.1 }}` ?

Comment: I found the problem - template didn't display data because there was the number instead of string. When I changed e.g data[2]['Tuesday'] = 7 to data['2']['Tuesday'] = 7 then everything is okay. Thanks

Comment: the safer solution would be to avoid passing a `defaultdict` to the template, cf my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: avoid passing defaultdicts to Django templates if you fancy your mental health ;)

Ok the OP found a workaround and doing so led me to understand what the problem really was, so I figured I would post this answer anyway because it's the kind of obvious-once-you-figured-it-out behaviours that can make you loose hours and quite a few hairs.

The problem here is a combination of how Django templates lookup values and how a `defaultdict` works. To resolve `{{ data.1 }}`, Django doesn't know whether `1` is supposed to be an int (`1`) or a string (`u"1"`), so it first calls `data.__getitem__()` with the string `u"1"`  then - if the call raised a `KeyError` - with the int `1`. This can be seen with this code (py2.7.x, django 1.10.x):

```
>>> from django.template import Template, Context
>>> class DW(dict):
...     def __getitem__(self, key):
...         print "DW.__getitem__(<%s> %r)" % (type(key), key)
...         return super(DW, self).__getitem__(key)
... 
>>> dw = DW()
>>> tpl = Template("this is '{{ data.1 }}'")
>>> tpl.render(Context({"data": dw}))
DW.__getitem__(<<type 'unicode'>> u'1')
DW.__getitem__(<<type 'int'>> 1)
u"this is ''"
```

Now the problem is that a `defauldict` with create missing keys on key lookup (in `__getitem__`), not only on key assignment (`__setitem__`), as one can easily check by oneself:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> dd = defaultdict(int)
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {})
>>> dd["1"]
0
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 0})
>>> dd[1]
0
>>> dd
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'1': 0, 1: 0})
>>>
```

Now since the OP was using a defaultdict with int keys and Django first tries with strings, the defaultdict would silently creates a new entry for the (missing) `u"1"` key and return the default value (in this case an empty dict).